# Will doing a git push after a file has been deleted by another user cause it to automatically return

Tags: git, repository

Say there is a git repository that multiple people are using. Someone deletes a file and pushes his changes, so that the file should no longer be a part of the repository.

If someone else who had done a pull before the file was deleted were to do a git push later, would the file be put back into the repository?

Comment: did it give you an error ? can you paste here.

Comment: He would have to merge the changes beforehand, and that would remove the file (since the changes from the removal would take precedence over doing nothing to it). I've just checked it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, due to the way Git is built you cannot push until you pull.

Quick psuedo-example:

1. Bob clones Alice's repo
2. Alice deletes a file and pushes to master
3. Bob modifies his repo and attempts a push, but encounters an error that his repo is out of date!
4. Bob pulls the new changes, and unless he modified the file to be deleted, his copy goes away. (If he did modify it, he'll have to finish the merge manually)
5. Bob pushes his new code without the file, or with the file **if and only if** his merge required him to keep the file Alice deleted.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is literally "no", but the problem is that the *question* does not make sense, so that this answer is nearly useless.

There are two "big picture" errors in the question.  One is a very natural error due to odd Git terminology.

## The opposite of push is not pull

In Git, the opposite of `git push` is actually `git fetch`.

This seems like saying that the opposite of "left" is "orange", or the opposite of "forwards" is "sideways".  The problem is that, way back in the mists of time, `push` and `pull` were *intended* to be opposite counterparts, but then it was discovered that `pull` did too much, and sometimes—or often—did the wrong thing.  It had to be split up.

#### pull = fetch + something else

The `git pull` command does *two* things:

- It runs `git fetch` (in a slightly modified way from standard `git fetch`, but you can just run standard `git fetch` when you break this down into its two parts).
- Then, it runs another Git command.

  By default the second command is `git merge`, but `git rebase` is actually more often the correct thing to do.  Git therefore allows you to configure `git pull` to run `git rebase` as its second thing.

You probably should never<sup>1</sup> use `git pull`.  Instead, run `git fetch` and then run `git rebase` (if that's what you want, which it usually is) or `git merge` (if that's what you want, which is not "never" but is rarer).

#### push checks that you're "in sync"

Unless you use the `--force` option or equivalent, `git push` will refuse to push unless you (the push-er) are already up to date with the other Git (the push-ee).  To get up to date, you must run `git fetch`, and then `git merge` or `git rebase`.

Normally, no one should use (or have to use) `--force` on shared branches.  (The `--force` flag is meant for special cases, like "pickup" branches, or any other situation where all participants using the shared repository have agreed that they accept "upstream rebases" or other commit rollback operations.)

## At this level of operation, Git deals in commits, not files.

These commands—`push` and `fetch`—work with *commits*, not files.

The second half of a `pull`—the `merge` or `rebase`—does have to deal with files.  It's during this second half that whoever is *operating* Git must reconcile any changes *they* have made, against any changes their `git fetch` step brought in from the other Git repository.

The opposite of `push`, though, is `fetch`.  Both `push` and `fetch` work strictly on the level of *commits*, and commits don't add or delete files or change file contents.  Commits are, instead, much more like snapshots.  Each commit is like a tarball, except for having the ability to move back to previous commits ("earlier releases", as it were).  And, of course, Git does a good job of doing fancy compression so that instead of thousands of tarballs, each with a complete copy of the tree, you have thousands of commits, each with a complete copy of the tree, but with *automatic sharing* between all the copies so that they take much less space.

Switching from one commit to another means uninstalling the first commit's tarball and then installing the second commit's tarball.  There can be no issue here with a file, or even part of a file, "coming back" unless the second commit's tarball has that file in it.  It's either all there, or not at all there.

It's the *merge or rebase* step where someone (generally a human) must decide whether to keep, drop, or bring back a file.  The human makes the decision and then does a `git commit` to make a new snapshot (tarball equivalent).  In some (very easy) cases Git can make this decision automatically (although even then it is not always correct, and it's wise to check that Git has done the right thing).

In one even-simpler case, there is nothing to merge or rebase.  In this case the second half of `git pull` is trivial—it does only a "label move", regardless of whether it's `git merge` or `git rebase`—which always succeeds.  There is nothing to get wrong, so in this case `git pull` actually works.  Of course, if you break it down into its two halves, by running `git fetch` and then whichever second command fits your purposes best, that *also* works.

In other words, there's never<sup>2</sup> a situation where `git pull` is *better* than `git fetch` followed by whichever Git command is most appropriate to your workflow.  So you should continue to avoid `git pull`.

---

<sup>1</sup>At least, not until you have a good understanding of the underlying details, and know what to do about a failed merge-or-rebase, and how to tell that apart from a failed fetch.

<sup>2</sup>There's a brief window of Git versions in the 1.8 and 1.9 range where `git pull` can do something fancy that the two-command version can't.  However, it can only do it *once*: if something goes wrong in the middle and you have to start over for any reason, the second `git pull` can't do the fancy trick any more.  If your Git is version 2.0 or later, `git rebase` has the fancy trick built in, and it *does* work if you have to restart.